# People api filter contacts

Tags: google-people-api

If I understand it correctly Google recommend to use the people api instead of the contacts api if you only need read only access. I'm looking for an option to search for contacts on name or company is this possible with the people api or is this only possible with the contacts v3 api.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.  https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1.  if you look at the current schema, they don't provide you a method to do query.